# VSTO addin in Outlook 2019 not working in Outlook 2016

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have big problem, my VSTO Outlook addin work in Outlook 2019 (visual studio 2019 and tested in Outlook 2019) but doenst work in version 2016.

No errors, no problems detected in Outlook 2016, Addin is loaded but do nothing.

Do anyone same experience and know how to fix it ?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried to step through your code? Anything in the Windows Event log? Outlook logs the addins it loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i know i got -1 for my question, but only way how i can figure this out, was install office 2016 and debug from visual studio 2019.

Comment: so what was the reason? Looks like I have the same problem cause the behavior is different from 2019 to 2016 outlook

Comment: the behavior is different because of the MS Exchange. He checks the file size limit before my event fire